# How should I made this process tree with fork in C?

Tags: c, for-loop, process, fork, binary-tree

everyone.

I am taking a course in operating systems and I have the task to programm the following process tree in C with fork. The program must receive 2 arguments the height and the width (of 3 and 2 respectively) and create the tree of this image :

[image]

On the image, P.I = Parent Process ,Hijo N= N Child Process, Nieto N = N Grandson and Bisnieto N = N Great Grandson.

The code has to be made from the following template:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
 int i, height, width;
 if (argc!= 3) exit(0);
 height = atoi(argv[1]); /* height */
 width = atoi(argv[2]); /* width */
 /* Your code goes here */
 printf("I am the process %d and my father is %d\n", getpid(), 
getppid());
 sleep(1);
 return 0;
}
```

I have made several codes but I cannot find the solution, the closest I have been is the next code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int
main (int argc, char *argv[]) 
{  
int i,x, height, width;  
pid_t pid,pid2; 
if (argc != 3)
    exit (0);  
height = atoi (argv[1]);    /* height */
width = atoi (argv[2]); /* width */  
    /* Your code goes here */ 
for (i = 1; i < height; i++)    
{
    pid=fork();
    if(pid<0){pid2 = fork();}
} 
printf ("I am the process %d and my father is %d\n", getpid (), getppid ());  
sleep (1);
return 0;

}
```

But the only thing missing is to create two child processes of the first process (P.I), hijo 2= child 2 of the diagram is not created.

I also tried to create a code that creates a chain of processes one after the other and another code that creates two processes from a parent, but I'm not sure how to join the codes to create this tree. Can someone help me?

This is the code of the chain that I made:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
 int i, height, width;
 pid_t pid,pid2;
 if (argc!= 3) exit(0);
 height = atoi(argv[1]); /* height */
 width = atoi(argv[2]);
    for (int i=0; i<height; i++)     
    {
        pid = fork();
        if (pid == -1) { /* handle error*/ }
        else if (pid == 0) {
            printf("Soc el process %d y meu pare es %d\n", getpid(),getppid());
        }
        else { // parent process
            wait(NULL);
            exit(0);
        }
    }
  printf("Soc el process %d y meu pare es %d\n", getpid(),getppid());
}
```

The code I made that creates two children of one parent is this one:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
 int i, height, width;
 pid_t pid,pid2;
 if (argc!= 3) exit(0);
 height = atoi(argv[1]); /* height */
 width = atoi(argv[2]); /* width */
 /* tu codigo aqui */
 for(int i=0;i<width;i++) // loop will run n times (n=5)
    {
        if(fork() == 0)
        {
            printf("[son] pid %d from [parent] pid %d\n",getpid(),getppid());
            exit(0);
        
        }
    }
  printf("Soc el process %d y meu pare es %d\n", getpid(),getppid());
  for(int i=0;i<height;i++) // loop will run n times (n=5)
  wait(NULL);
}
```

I wanted to know if it is a better idea to join the two codes or modify the first one and how to do it: C

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because asking for help on homework requires that the post ask a specific question about a specific problem.

Answer (score 1):

The diagram you have shown in your question, depict the behaviour when height is `3` and width is `2` and the behaviour is:
Every process should have `2` (equal to `width`) child processes and out of which one child process will exit and one will continue with forking its `2` (equal to `width`) child processes... and so on. When the `height` is reached, fork `1` child process (and let it exit).

What happen when width will be `3` (or to be more precise, width `> 2`?

I am assuming that, in the case, when width is `> 2` a process should fork number of child process equal to `width` and all child process should exit except one of the child process which will further fork the child processes equal to the given number of `width` and this goes on until the height of tree reached. The last parent process will fork `width - 1` number of child processes and none of these child processes will further fork any other child process. With this assumption, `width` should be `>= 1`.

Implementation:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int height, width;

    if (argc != 3) {
        printf ("Invalid number of arguments, exiting..\n");
        exit (0);
    }

    height = atoi (argv[1]);
    width = atoi (argv[2]);

    if ((height <= 0) || (width <= 0)) {
        printf ("Invalid input.\n"); // error handling can be better
        exit (0);
    }

    printf ("Parent process, my pid = %d, height = %d, width = %d\n", getpid(), height, width);

    for (int i = 0; i < height; ++i) {
        printf ("\nMy pid : %d, current height of tree : %d, forking..\n", getpid(), i);
        pid_t pid;

        for (int j = 0; j < width; ++j) {
            if ((i + 1 == height) && (j == 0)) {
                continue;
            }

            pid = fork();

            if (pid == -1) { 
                printf ("Fork failed\n");
            } else if (pid == 0) {
                if (j) {
                    printf ("My pid = %d, [my parent : %d], I am EXITING..\n", getpid(), getppid());
                    exit(0);
                } else {
                    printf ("My pid = %d, [my parent : %d], I will fork other child processes..\n", getpid(), getppid());
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        if (pid) {
            break;
        } else {
            // added sleep for sequenced output, otherwise it's not needed
            sleep (1);
        }
    }

    while (wait(NULL) > 0);
    printf ("pid %d : I am EXITING\n", getpid());

    // added sleep for sequenced output, otherwise it's not needed
    sleep (1);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
# ./a.out 3 2
Parent process, my pid = 3827, height = 3, width = 2

My pid : 3827, current height of tree : 0, forking..
My pid = 3828, [my parent : 3827], I will fork other child processes..
My pid = 3829, [my parent : 3827], I am EXITING..

My pid : 3828, current height of tree : 1, forking..
My pid = 3830, [my parent : 3828], I will fork other child processes..
My pid = 3831, [my parent : 3828], I am EXITING..

My pid : 3830, current height of tree : 2, forking..
My pid = 3832, [my parent : 3830], I am EXITING..
pid 3830 : I am EXITING
pid 3828 : I am EXITING
pid 3827 : I am EXITING
```

Diagrammatic representation:

```
     --------
     | 3827 |
     --------
       |    \
       |     \
       |      \
       |       \
       |        --------
       |        | 3829 |
     --------   --------
     | 3828 | 
     -------- 
       |    \
       |     \
       |      \
       |       \
       |        --------
       |        | 3831 |
     --------   --------
     | 3830 | 
     -------- 
            \
             \
              \
               \
                --------
                | 3832 |
                --------
```

Output for `height = 3` and `width = 4`:

```
# ./a.out 3 4
Parent process, my pid = 4052, height = 3, width = 4

My pid : 4052, current height of tree : 0, forking..
My pid = 4053, [my parent : 4052], I will fork other child processes..
My pid = 4054, [my parent : 4052], I am EXITING..
My pid = 4055, [my parent : 4052], I am EXITING..
My pid = 4056, [my parent : 4052], I am EXITING..

My pid : 4053, current height of tree : 1, forking..
My pid = 4058, [my parent : 4053], I will fork other child processes..
My pid = 4059, [my parent : 4053], I am EXITING..
My pid = 4060, [my parent : 4053], I am EXITING..
My pid = 4061, [my parent : 4053], I am EXITING..

My pid : 4058, current height of tree : 2, forking..
My pid = 4062, [my parent : 4058], I am EXITING..
My pid = 4063, [my parent : 4058], I am EXITING..
My pid = 4064, [my parent : 4058], I am EXITING..
pid 4058 : I am EXITING
pid 4053 : I am EXITING
pid 4052 : I am EXITING
```